# SwiftUI Picker Foreach with @state list

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
class MyState {
   @Published var colors = [String]()
   @Published private var selectedColor = "Red"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myState: MyState

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Please choose a color", selection: $myState.selectedColor) {
                ForEach(myState.colors, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0).tag($0)
                }
            }
            Text("You selected: \(selectedColor)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            fetchData() // will update MyState object's variables
        }
    }
}
```

Issue:

[image]

1. Select another element
2. The selection gets lost if I click again the picker

I have a list of empty String because I don't have initial data until the API calls.
I am updating `colors` list like assigning a new list.

```
colors = ["newString", "newString2",...]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this example code:

```
class MyState: ObservableObject {  // <-- here
   @Published var colors = [String]()
   @Published var selectedColor = "Red" // <-- here, no private
}

struct ContentView: View {
 //   @EnvironmentObject var myState: MyState
    @StateObject var myState = MyState() // <-- for testing

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Please choose a color", selection: $myState.selectedColor) {
                ForEach(myState.colors, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0).tag($0)
                }
            }
            Text("You selected: \(myState.selectedColor)") // <-- here
        }
        .onAppear {
           // fetchData() // will update MyState object's variables
            // -- for testing
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                myState.colors = ["green", "white", "blue", "black"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```